# Use Maven credentials in setting.xml with Gradle

Tags: maven, gradle, dependencies, continuous-integration, artifactory

I have some Gradle projects, but I would like to avoid to load credentials explicitly in `build.gradle` file.
An example of what I would like to avoid is:

```
        maven {
            credentials {
                username "$maven_user"
                password "$maven_password"
            }
            url 'https://my-maven-repo'
        }
```

I would like to avoid to have username and password fields in `gradle.build`, even if those values can be loaded from the local host for example from `~/.gradle/gradle.properties`.

What I would like to achieve is to load credentials from `~/.m2/settings.xml` and to specify only the maven repository url in `gradle.build`.

Is it possible to do that? I did several attempts but it looks like that Gradle ignore the credentials in `settings.xml`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the [Maven Settings Plugin](https://github.com/mark-vieira/gradle-maven-settings-plugin)

Set it up like that :

New way :

```
plugins {
    id 'net.linguica.maven-settings' version '0.5'
}
```

Old way (Gradle 2.0 or earlier) :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'net.linguica.gradle:maven-settings-plugin:0.5'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'net.linguica.maven-settings'
```

Then simply declare you repositories :

```
repositories {
    maven {
        name 'your-repo'
        url 'http://.....'
    }
}
```

Assuming in `~/.m2/settings.xml` you have something like :

```
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>your-repo</id>
        <username>user</username>
        <password>pass</password>
    </server>
</servers>
```

Comment: What's the syntax when using Kotlin-dsl? `maven(url="url",name="repo")` doesn't work.

Comment: ```
import java.net.URI
plugins {
    id("net.linguica.maven-settings") version "0.5"
}

repositories {
    maven {
        name = "repo"
        url = URI("https://")
    }
}
```